# Is it possible to have hidden and window mode in same .exe in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, hidden, visible

I wounder if is possible to have in same exe silent and window mode, which could be defined via command parameters in c++?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a form-project if I am right. In this project you would have a sub main as starting file (same as in a console-project). In this sub main you could read out the parameters and decide if you want to open a form or to continue in the current sub. I developed this under VS2008.

^^ Oh sorry, this solution is only prooved in .Net (VB, C#). I don't know if it will work with C++...

Answer (score 1):

Sure. In fact, every Windows GUI program starts hidden until you actually call `CreateWindow` (directly or indirectly). No call, no window.